# Nested loops for beginners

Tags: nested-loops

I can't seem to understand the logic of nested loops. 
Any tips or easy examples about how to make nested loops less complicated? 
 New to programming. Thanks.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific what you mean? Otherwise, we have to write volumes of books here!

Comment: What is so difficult about the concept of a loop inside a loop? (Inside a loop, inside a loop, inside a loop and so on...) Each separate loop does not need to "know" it is nested; it only need to *loop* once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested loops are essential for a good programmer. They are usually used to manage matrices in order to avoid code repetition. Let's have an example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
      Log.i("i:", i);
      Log.i("j:", j);
   }
}
```

After using this code (Java) several numbers are written in the log of the IDE. As you can see, the inner loop is run first (in our example 5 strings are written, because the loop needs to be run 5 times in order to make `j` become equal to 5). After the first 5 results are carried out, the program increments `i` and runs the inner loop again. The outer loop is also run 5 times, indeed it takes 5 times to make `i` equal to 5. 
 
As you can notice, the code written inside the two nested loops is run `i*j` times.

I hope my answer was clear enaugh.